# Does Ninject have an equivalent of Autofac's TypedParameter or ResolvedParameter?

Tags: ioc-container, ninject, autofac

In Autofac, it's possible to specify a TypedParameter on the registration of a service giving a specific value or delegate which will be passed into the constructor of the service. The actual parameter on the constructor will be discovered by type during resolution/instantiation.

In Ninject, I can only find support for named parameters (i.e., knowing the actual name of the .ctor parameter ahead of time). Ninject will otherwise discover un-specified constructor parameters and try to resolve any types required by checking with the container.

However, this isn't specific enough for my needs, as I have multiple instances of the same type which I need to pass into constructors of different service instances.

I want to give Ninject a specific factory delegate or value for a constructor parameter given only a type as a qualifier, not a parameter name. I also don't want to have a dependency to Ninject by decorating the constructor parameter with any attributes.

Is this possible? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Secondary point - if Ninject has an equivalent of an Autofac ResolvedParameter (i.e. some way of providing my own delegate which tells Ninject if the parameter matches my filter during parameter discovery) this will also suit my needs. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what you want are conditional bindings. The most universal one is:

```
Bind<IFoo>().To<Foo>().When(request => SomeFancyFilter(); }
```

I don't know what fits best for you as you do not really specify what you really want to achieve. But I guess one of the following ones should apply:

```
Bind<IFoo>().To<Foo1>().WhenInjectedInto<Class1>()
Bind<IFoo>().To<Foo2>().WhenInjectedInto<Class2>()
```

Or:
Create your Own Attributes e.g. Bar1, Bar2 and add them to your constructors:

```
public Class1([Bar1]IFoo foo)
public Class2([Bar2]IFoo foo)
public Class3([Bar2]IFoo foo)

Bind<IFoo>().To<Foo1>().WhenTargetHas<Bar1Attribute>()
Bind<IFoo>().To<Foo2>().WhenTargetHas<Bar2Attribute>()
```

Comment: Very nice!  Where can I find the documentation for these?  (Ninject in general seems to have very little in the way of documentation!)

Comment: Yes there is little documentation. Our time is limited and we have to focus at the most importatnt things. Everyone is welcome to support to get this changed. the best source of documentation currently are the unittests and the sourcecode documentation. Further more the interface is easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question 100%.  Can you provide an example of what you are trying to do? This looks like it might suit your needs:

https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Multi-injection

If not, I get the feeling that you will need to make a factory method like this example:

```
    public override void Load()
    {
        Func<Ninject.Activation.IContext, IMyInterface> factoryFunc = 
            (context) => {
                return new ConcreteFactory(...parameters...); 
            };

        Bind<IMyInterface>().ToMethod(factoryFunc);
    }
```

In the method of your factoryFunc, you can perhaps inspect the context (which is the binding context) to return your desired factory method.  Specifically, you can inspect `context.Request.Service` or `context.Request.Target`.

Again, I would need to see an example of what you're doing to really answer your question.